# Chrome extension to disable bait-and-switch

Tags: chrome

I often see many websites, including major news sites, and even the Google search engine itself, that do something I find to be extremely unethical.

In these sites, when you hover a link, the bottom bar shows you the url the link will send you to, but when you actually click it, it sends you to a different url, most likely for click tracking, and that page then sends you (hopefully) to your originally intended destination.

I think they do this by showing the bait url in the `href` part of the `<a>` tag, and then rewrite it via JavaScript with an `onClick` script. You can actually see the real URL when you click on it, and if you click on a link, and before releasing the mouse you press the escape key, the link will correctly show the real destination for the link.

I would like to have an extension that either disables switching the destination url, and force the browser to go to the link that is originally set in the html tag, or preferably, show me the true destination of links without having me click-and-escape from it.

As I don't know the actual name of this deceiving technique, I don't really know how to search for it. I've tried a few searches, but they come up with unrelated extensions.